# Use DLL file in my URL link , c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dll

I'm  writing a c# code  to do :
1- get file file zipped folder. 
2- add file to zipped folder.
3- if the file is Image then do compression and re-size the image with some conditions.

and its working perfectly :)

i need to put the code inside a library and build it so i can get a DLL file, and that's easy too i have no problem with it.

the problem is: how can i pass parameter to that DLL file. i need to use it like this:

```
<a href='myDLL.dll?image=XX&width=XX&height=XX&compression=XX' />
```

please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible to call a dll from html, why you didn't use a [HttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx) for this?

Comment: well, we currently use this:  http://www.menafn.com/charting/Imager.dll?Image=/updates/pr/2016-03/AFP_fe8aca8e8d3609844d4cf600f9199423aa6c04bc.jpg&width=60&Compression=80    and its working  but i need to change something and i dont have the code of this DLL file so im writing it again

Comment: if you implement an HttpHandler you can get the parameters by query string in HttpContext

Comment: if it is a .net dll you can decompile it using tools like Just Decompile

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a dll file which can be usable by other project, you should create a new "Class Library" project. This is a specific type of a project which returns only a .dll file as a result. Then you should add this dll to your other projects in order to use the functions.

Here is more info about the topic:
[MSDN Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164.aspx)

Comment: i can do that .... my problem is i need to use the DLL inside HTML imag tag like  : <img src=' myDLL.dll?image=XX&width=XX' /> instead of <img src=' myPAGE.aspx?image=XX&width=XX' />

Comment: Html links and codes works only with the browser and does client side jobs. You cannot access a .dll file, it's a part of server side environment. 

So where is your C# code to create zip files exactly?  You should add the class library to the server you do the zipping job. 

You may consider adding "runat=server" tag to any HTML, if you want your tag to trigger codebehind.

Comment: Hakan: see this for example:http://www.menafn.com/charting/Imager.dll?Image=/updates/pr/2017-10/N_9519389e-5image_story.jpg&height=155&Compression=80